# FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I've converted my image file to grayscale, then blurred it and used canny, the result is in uint8 but still I'm getting the error. Please help!

```
    shapes= cv2.imread('E:\Photos\shapes.jpg')
    shapes= cv2.resize(shapes, (640,360))
    shapes_gray= cv2.cvtColor(shapes, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    shapes_blur= cv2.GaussianBlur(shapes_gray, (5, 5), 1)
    shapes_edges= cv2.Canny(shapes_blur, 50, 50)
    blank= np.zeros_like(shapes)
    
    def getContours(img):
        contours, hierarchy= cv2.findContours(shapes, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        for i in contours:
            area= cv2.contourArea(i)
            print(area)

    print(getContours(shapes_edges))
```

Answer (score 1):

you are passing `shapes` to `findContours`. that is a color picture.

I believe you meant to pass `shapes_gray` or `shapes_blur` or `shapes_edges` instead.

Comment: Hey, yes, I forgot to add the line, however when I tried getContours(shapes_edges), it showed the same error

Comment: check `.dtype` of your argument to `findContours`

Comment: thanks, I got my issue, I was only looking at the argument while calling the function which i wrote as shapes_edges, but overlooked the one inside the definition of the function which i wrote as shapes which should be img instead, poor me!